# Создание собственной команды

Tags: wpf, .net

Для использования собственных команд:

```
public class DataCommands
{
    public static RoutedCommand Delete { get; set;}
    public static RoutedCommand Edit { get; set; }
    static DataCommands()
    {
        InputGestureCollection inputs = new InputGestureCollection();
        inputs.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.E, ModifierKeys.Control, "Ctrl+E"));
        edit = new RoutedCommand("Edit", typeof(DataCommands), inputs);
        inputs = new InputGestureCollection();
        inputs.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.D, ModifierKeys.Control, "Ctrl+D"));
        delete = new RoutedCommand("Delete", typeof(DataCommands), inputs);
    }
}
```

Добавил ссылку на странице, где буду использовать:

```
xmlns:command="clr-namespace:WpfApplProject.Commands"
```

А как теперь добавить эти две команды к коллекции команд:

```
<Page.CommandBindings>
<CommandBinding Command="Undo" Executed="UndoCommandBinding_Executed"                       CanExecute="SaveCommandBinding_CanExecute" /> //Библиотечная команда
</Page.CommandBindings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и пишите:

```
 <!-- для команды Edit -->
 <CommandBinding Command="command:DataCommands.Edit" ... />
```